# Joining curves in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have drawn two spiro curves in Inkscape. Both have the same endpoint, but when zooming in on the connection between these two curves, it does not look fine:
[image]

Note the gap between both curves. What I finally want to have is this (simulated using paint):
[image]

Getting both curves red is not the problem, but note the rounded edge that I want to have. How can I get this rounded edge? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look for the 'Join" and "Cap" settings in the Fill & Stroke panel > Stroke style. Caps are applied at the ends of curves, and joins at corner nodes.

You may get different results for two shared endpoints (each will have its own round cap) than for a corner (a round join will fill the outer bend).

Answer (score 0):

1. Select both lines
2. Choose Path/Combine (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)
3. Choose the points tool (<kbd>F2</kbd>) and select the two endpoints (drag a rectangle around them)
4. Merge the endpoints
5. Choose Object/Fill and contour (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
6. Set Join to rounded

<sup>This was translated from a German Inkscape. Feel free to change to the correct terms.</sup>